# How can I find the latest stable version of a crate using cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to know the latest actix-web version, so I executed `cargo search actix-web`. The result is `actix-web = "4.0.0-beta.1"`, showing the beta version number.

I want to know the latest **stable** version number; how do I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, I only care to know about the version number of a crate when I'm going to add the crate to my Cargo.toml. In those cases, I use two extra Cargo subcommands from the [cargo-edit project](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit):

- `cargo add` — adds the current stable version of a crate to `Cargo.toml`. Options exist for allowing prerelease versions or marking it as a build / dev dependency.
- `cargo upgrade` — updates the version of a crate already in `Cargo.toml`. Similar to `cargo update`, but also changes `Cargo.toml` in addition to `Cargo.lock`.

Comment: Note that `cargo upgrade` comes from a third-party extension (though there are apparently plans to add it to upstream Cargo): https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit

Answer (score 1):

```
cargo show --json $1 | python -m json.tool | jq ".versions[].num"
```